# How come my array is not being filled with objects/Displayed?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, 2d

So basically I want to fill an array with objects and then display it. (Later these objects will be able to be Seat as 'Booked' which will make them be displayed as an X in the array.)

However I keep getting an error whenever I go to execute the methods that would make and display the array.

Here is my code:

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Seat cinemaactual = new Seat("Cinema");
        Seat[][] cinema = new Seat[10][22];

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer, contiune;



        int number, check = 0, category, id;




        do {



            System.out.print("Welcome to the Theatre Booking System. (QUIT to exit)"
                    + "\nWould you like to purchase tickets or list available seats?"
                    + "(/Purchase/List/Help)");
            answer = scan.nextLine();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")) {
                do {

                    System.out.println("Please choose the cateogry of ticket "
                            + "you would like, followed by who the ticket is for"
                            + "and the amount required. (separated by a space)\n"
                            + "1. Gold\n2. Silver\n3. Bronze\n\n1. Adult\n2."
                            + " Child\n3. Concession");
                    category = scan.nextInt();
                    number = scan.nextInt();
                    id = scan.nextInt();
                    if (category == 1 || category == 2 || category == 3 && id == 1 || id == 2 || id == 3) {

                        ticket.SetType(category);
                        if (category == 1) {
                            ticket.SetName("Gold");
                        } else if (category == 2) {
                            ticket.SetName("Siler");
                        } else {
                            ticket.SetName("Bronze");
                        }
                        ticket.SetNumber(number);
                        ticket.SetID(id);
                        if (id == 1) {
                            ticket.SetCategory("Adult");
                        } else if (id == 2) {
                            ticket.SetCategory("Child");
                        } else {
                            ticket.SetCategory("Bronze");
                        }
                        System.out.print("You have selected"
                                + ticket.GetNumber() + " " + ticket.GetName()
                                + " ticket(s) at the" + ticket.GetCategory() + " price .");

                        ticket.BuyTicket(category, id, number);


                    } else {

                        System.out.print("Sorry, incorrect input, please enter an apropriate value.");
                        check = scan.nextInt();
                    }
                } while (check == 0 || check > 3);

                do {
                    System.out.print("Would you like to perchase more tickets? (Yes/No)");
                    contiune = scan.nextLine();




                } while (contiune.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));



            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                cinemaactual.CreateTheatre(cinema);
                cinemaactual.DisplayTheatre(cinema);

            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                // Code for help
            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            System.out.print("Sorry, incorrect input please enter"
                    + " a valid input (Purchase/List/Help or QUIT to exit");
            answer = scan.nextLine();

        } while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")
                || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("List")
                || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help")
                || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));


    }
```

Seat Class Methods that would create/Fill Array:

```
    public void SetType(String x) {

        type = x;
    }

    public boolean SetStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void GetStatus(boolean x) {
        status = x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String Seat = type;

        return type;
    }

    public String BookSeat() {
        type = "x";
        return type;
    }

    public Seat[][] CreateTheatre(Seat[][] x) {


        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
            for (int col = 8; col < 12; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 19; row < 23; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
            for (int col = 8; col < 12; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 4; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 3; col < 5; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
            for (int col = 5; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 4; row < 7; row++) {
            for (int col = 9; col < 12; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 14; row < 20; row++) {
            for (int col = 3; col < 5; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
            for (int col = 5; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 16; row < 20; row++) {
            for (int col = 9; col < 12; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 9; row < 14; row++) {
            for (int col = 6; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 7; row < 16; row++) {
            for (int col = 9; col < 12; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public void DisplayTheatre(Seat[][] x) {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < x[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(x[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To generate a random index: new java.util.Random().nextInt()

Comment: Instead of posting the whole project here, just post the relevant part of the code along with the stacktrace or error message. That should be enough for us to help on finding out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CreateTheatre(...)` you first have to make sure, that the arrays are actually as large, as you process in the `for` loops, if they are smaller, trying to access them throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Ah ok, so 
`for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");`
Doesn't fill the array, with a new seat object?

Comment: @user1719605 I havn't examined your code as a whole, but on the first glance I understood that this is the problem, maybe or maybe not...

Comment: This is the error message I get when I run the code, and type in the input that would execute the methods. If this helps. Exception in thread ""main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
 at cinemasystem.Seat.CreateTheatre(Seat.java:65)
 at cinemasystem.CinemaSystem.main(CinemaSystem.java:89)
Java Result: 1"

Comment: OK, I did that, it is now loading the values in the array and displaying them. However I now have the problem of it displaying null, in the coordinates where I don't want anything displayed, is there a way to make it display white space instead of 'null'?

Comment: @user1719605 Before displaying it, check `if( x[row][col] != null)`.